How to dynamically resize Image [coil] in Android Compose application
My current Android Compose application allows the user to set the size of app icons using a slider.
the slider range is from 0.5 to 2 e.g. allow the user to reduce the icons size between 50% and 200%.
i have the following compose code
var currentValue by remember { mutableIntStateOf(uiController.settings.getScaleFactorInt()) }

val dynamicIconSize: Int by remember { derivedStateOf { (24 * (currentValue / 100.0F)).toInt() } }

with the coil AsyncImage beig defined as follows:-
AsyncImage(
            model = uiController.hotspotSettings?.fullIconUrl,
            contentDescription = null,
            modifier = Modifier.size(dynamicIconSize.dp)
        )

this works however the user experience is very bad.
I guess its because the image is being redrawn excessively as the user drags the slider.
how can i achieve a smoother dynamic change and allow the user to set icon size?
the slider is defined as follows:-
CustomSlider(
            modifier = Modifier
                .weight(1f),
            currentValue = currentValue,
            maxValue = 200,
            minValue = 50,
            onValueChanged = { customScale ->
                currentValue = customScale
                val validatedValue = if (customScale >= 50) customScale else 50
                onValueChanged(validatedValue)
            }


I don't see anything wrong with the code, except probably that you use modifier = Modifier.size(dynamicIconSize.dp) to scale the content instead of contentScale = FixedScale(...). Maybe it is the Custom Slider? Have you tried replacing that with the built-in Slider() just to rule it out?

@Leviathan Is FixedScale going to scale the image within its bounds or is it going to also scale the Composable bounds?

If you don't restrict the AsyncImage's size then it will grow and shrink as needed to accomodate the scaled image's size.

You should not use derivedStateOf in your current scenario. It should be used when you have a frequently changing state variable, but only want to recompose on a certain threshold.

Caution: derivedStateOf is expensive, and you should only use it to avoid unnecessary recomposition when a result hasn't changed.

You can try to use the remember with keys instead and test whether it makes any difference in performance:
val dynamicIconSize: Int by remember(currentValue) { (24 * (currentValue / 100.0F)).toInt() }

Besides that, as Leviathan said, make sure that your CustomSlider implementation is not the bottleneck. Especially verify that you are
choosing an appropriate step size. If your CustomSlider causes a recomposition at each 0.001f step, this will introduce an unnecessary overhead.
You can try to use FixedScale instead of using the size Modifier, as suggested by Leviathan:
// TODO: adjust calculation accordingly
val dynamicIconSize: Float by remember(currentValue) { currentValue / 150 }

AsyncImage(
    model = uiController.hotspotSettings?.fullIconUrl,
    contentDescription = null,
    contentScale = FixedScale(dynamicIconSize)
)

Please report back if it changes anything.
